# Ученик неподготовлен, доклад не подготовлен

Tags: причастия, прилагательные

Новые сотрудники не подготовленны. Новые сотрудники неподготовленны_. Раздельное или слитное написание зависит от смысла, это определяет сам пишущий.
Так отвечает на вопрос "Грамота". Но у Розенталя однозначно: ученик неподготовлен (прилагательное) – доклад не подготовлен (причастие). Кто же прав?

Answer (score 3):

Они говорят о разных вещах. Розенталь говорит о правописании НЕ с кратким причастием и отличии краткого причастия от краткого прилагательного: доклад не подготовлен(его не подготовили),а  вот ученик неподготовлен - прилагательное, потому что обозначает качественный признак "малокомпетентен, малообразован". Во множ. ч. - ученики неподготовленны (малокомпетентны), но: ученики не подготовлены к экзамену (причастие, потому что есть зависимое слово - их не подготовили к экзамену).

"Грамота" говорит, что краткие прилагательные могут писаться слитно, если утверждается неподготовленность(отрицательный признак), и раздельно, если подчёркивается отрицание подготовленности (положительного признака). Она не ведёт речь о причастии.