# Неподготовленный к экзамену ученик — это правильно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

1. Из словаря: **ПОДГОТОВИТЬ,** кого-что. 3. (нсв. также готовить). **Дать необходимые знания, навыки кому-л. для чего-л.,** обучить кого-л. для какой-л. деятельности, развить. **П. к экзаменам.** П. врачей. П. трактористов. П. в вуз. П. к поступлению в университет. Голос не подготовлен для арии.
2. ***Неподготовленный*** — это прилагательное или причастие?

**Больше похоже на причастие**: не подготовить ученика к экзаменам — не подготовленный к экзаменам ученик.

3. Но вот **у Розенталя:** ***ученик неподготовлен*** (прилагательное) — ***доклад не подготовлен*** (причастие).http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80 Пункт 5
4. Такой вопрос уже был на форуме, причем правильность данного утверждения была **с уверенностью подтверждена.**  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430807/Ученик-неподготовлен-доклад-не-подготовлен](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430807/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD)
5. Но вот пользователи сомневаются (а им экзамен сдавать) и утверждают, что **это причастие с раздельным написанием НЕ**: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/230060452

Так как же правильно? **Может Розенталь здесь не совсем точен?**

6. Есть еще вариант: разные решения для полной и краткой формы, но **как это обосновать**, обычно они совпадают? К тому же слитное написание "неподготовленный к экзамену ученик" вроде бы отмечено как правильное в методиках.
7. Но есть еще интересная версия. Составитель прав: **Неподготовленный к экзамену ученик — это правильно.** Но это надо убедительно доказать.

Comment: Хороший там ответ, где советуют "очень" вставить. *Очень неподготовленный к экзамену ученик* — проблемы со стилистикой.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***ученик неподготовлен к экзаменам, ученик неподготовлен***

**Пояснение**

**1. Парные причастия и отпричастные прилагательные (общая информация по теме)**

В общем случае это тема парных причастий и отпричастных прилагательных. В полной форме и при отсутствии зависимых слов нет необходимости в их различении, так как НЕ и с причастиями, и с прилагательными в этом случае  пишется слитно.

**В краткой  форме и при наличии зависимых слов** НЕ пишется раздельно с причастиями и слитно с прилагательными.

**Примеры**

**Причастие**: *несдержанное обещание, не сдержанное другом обещание, обещание не сдержано.*

Слово является **причастием**, если обозначает признак по действию; можно подобрать слово  в Т.п., обозначающее производителя или орудие действия; прямое значение слова, нельзя подобрать синонимичное прилагательное, нет однородных отношений с  прилагательными.

**Прилагательное:** *несдержанные (вспыльчивые) люди, несдержанные в общении люди, люди несдержанны.*

Слово является **прилагательным**, если обозначает качественный признак;
нельзя подобрать зависимое слово  в Т.п., обозначающее производителя или орудие действия; переносное значение слова, можно подобрать синонимичное прилагательное, возможны однородные отношения с прилагательными: несдержанный, вспыльчивый

**2. Особенности пары "неподготовленный доклад — неподготовленный ученик"**

(1) Обычно **переносного значення глагола нет в словаре**, поэтому прилагательное образуется не от глагола, а переходом причастия в прилагательное. Так, глагол **"сдержать"** имеет только прямое значение (сдержать обещание).

СДЕРЖАТЬ, св. 1.4. что. Исполнить (обещанное). С. обещание, клятву. С. своё слово (сделать то, что обещал).

(2) Но у глагола **"подготовить"** разные значения отмечены уже **в словаре:**

ПОДГОТОВИТЬ,  1. **Заранее привести в порядок всё необходимое для использования**, применения, употребления. Надо п. вагоны для погрузки. П. лекцию, роль, собрание. 2. Послужить основой чего-л., **создать, сформулировать.** Будни подготовили праздники. 3. (нсв. также готовить). **Дать необходимые знания, навыки** кому-л. для чего-л., обучить кого-л. для какой-л. деятельности, развить. П. к экзаменам.

**3. Вывод**

Поэтому **прилагательное "неподготовленный**" образуется непосредственно от глагола (не от причастия), соответственно, там нет обычных признаков парных выражений, то есть нет ПЕРЕНОСНОГО значения.

Но есть принципиально **разные значения**, поэтому различать эти значения **НЕОБХОДИМО**. Подготовить доклад — это **создать доклад,** подготовить ученика — это дать ему **нужные знания** (качественное изменение). Поэтому мы различаем эти значения с помощью **разной формы письма:** *ученик неподготовлен, неподготовленный к экзамену ученик — доклад не подготовлен*, доклад не подготовлен к указанному сроку.

**Именно это отличие** вызывает много трудностей в понимании данной темы, когда ошибаются даже хорошо знающие язык люди, а учащимся тем более сложно усвоить этот материал.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138429/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).

Comment: Да, согласен, что там больше качественное значение, но зависимые слова такого типа нарушают это. Пока не понимаю, почему оно должно быть одинаковым. Мне так не кажется.

Comment: *несдержанные в общении люди* — согласен, тогда должно быть как-то так: *неподготовленный в плане сдачи экзамена ученик* (сразу понял, что надо как-то так). Проверяем: *Очень неподготовленный в плане сдачи экзамена ученик.* Слово "очень" стилистику не портит.

Comment: oleedd  Прием из школьных времен:  А мы хорошо разобрались в теме! – Да? А я вот этот вопрос не поняла...  Далее задаете подружкам каверзный вопрос. Попробую задать вам.:  Солдаты, мальчишки, не обученные толком, ― в бой, а их командир роты… [Г. Я. Бакланов.  (1995)]   Как объяснить раздельное написание НЕ. Темы вроде похожи: неподготовленные к экзаменам, не обученные толком, в обоих случаях качественное значение, а письмо разное.

Comment: Не соглашусь. "*[Очень] неподготовленные к экзаменам*" — качественное значение здесь нарушает стилистику.

Comment: А вы без "очень" можете как-то обойтись или уже никак. Я спрашиваю:  в чем разница между "не обученные толком" и "неподготовленные к экзаменам". В словаре значения глаголов совпадают. Я напомню: ПОДГОТОВИТЬ 3.  Дать необходимые знания, навыки кому-л. для чего-л., ОБУЧИТЬ кого-л. для какой-л. деятельности, развить. П. к экзаменам.  Так почему одно прилагательное, а другое причастие? Нужен короткий и ясный ответ. Я это объясняла в комментариях (теперь они в чате), там есть ключевое слово. Но вы его, конечно, не услышали.

Comment: А как мне вам объяснить без подстановки? Она как раз всё расставляет по местам. В чём разница между этими словами: не обучил кто-то, а ученик сам не подготовился. "Неподготовленные" в значении прилагательного, когда нет зависимых слов!

Comment: Ответ НЕВЕРНЫЙ: ученика не подготовили к экзаменам, солдат не обучили толком. Это страдательные причастия, ученик здесь объект действия, а не субъект.  А КЛЮЧЕВЫЕ слова надо слышать и понимать.

Comment: Ответ верный. Чаще всего так, что ученик сам не подготовился. Умные ученики готовятся сами, без репетиторов. Чего это его должны готовить? К экзаменам обычно готовятся сами.

Comment: То есть переходим к морали, если больше сказать нечего. Ну ладно...

Comment: *Он пришёл на экзамен неподготовленным.* Здесь хоть как-то ощущается, что его не подготовили? Нет! Он сам не подготовился. Уже всё сказано. **Не должно быть зависимых слов!**

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы верите писателям, составителям заданий и т.п., считаете их "unmistakable". Ко всему надо относится со скепсисом, даже к Розенталю (каплю).

Comment: Все, oleedd, вы меня разочаровали...  Не подготовился – непереходный глагол,  а страдательные причастия образуются от переходных глаголов.  Так кому мне верить, Розенталю или вам? )) Учите матчать и до скорых встреч.

Comment: *Так кому мне верить, Розенталю или вам* — а я не перечу Розенталю, в отличие от вас (пишется раздельно, когда есть зависимые слова). Да здесь какая разница, что от чего образуется? Здесь смысл важен.

Comment: *Ты не подготовлен к уроку* — это значит, что он не виноват, его должны были подготовить,  потому что оно образовано не от возвратного глагола? Бред.

Comment: Вы в ответе не говорите, почему игнорируете зависимые слова. Там не обстоятельство времени, как у Розенталя. Эти зависимые слова не подходят для слитного написания.